# Store not loading from remote URL?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Just trying to get a Panel filled with a List that populates itself from a Store. All I get is a blank window. Its not even sending an HTTP request in the Network window of Chrome.

List:

```
myapp.companies_list = {
        fullscreen: true,
        title: 'Companies',
        iconCls: 'info',
        xtype: 'list',
        itemTpl: '{name}',
        store: {
            fields: ['name'],
            autoload: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'jsonp',
                url: base_url+'/index.php/mobile/companies',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'companies'
                }
            }
        },
        listeners:{
            initialize: function(){
                this.getStore().load();
            }
        }
    }
```

This will *not* work without the listener. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **autoLoad**, not **autoload**. Notice the capital **L**.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem, i place proxy setting into model instead into store and autoload works.

you could change jsonp into ajax or rest if doesnt work.